# Addresses of template function instantiations over T and T const

Tags: c++, function-pointers, instantiation, function-templates

Is it ever possible that in the following setup

```
template <typename T>
inline void id() {
    //...
}

template <typename T>
bool check() {
    return &id<T> == &id<T const>;
}
```

`check` will return `true` for some `T`? Does it depend on what is being done inside `id`? What does the standard have to say about this?

Comment: It is possible to return false. Try it out!

Comment: @juanchopanza my bad, of course i meant `true`.

Comment: Another complication is that MS VC++ will often merge template code when the generated machine code happen to be identical. Not standards compliant, but saves space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. Try `const int` or `int&` or `void()`.

---

There's a rule that top-level `const` qualifiers *collapse* if you get multiple of them through a `typedef` or a template argument, which means `check<int const>()` will return `true`.

[normative text pending]

Then there's a rule that ignores top-level `const` on things it doesn't work on, like references or function types. That means `check<int&>` and `check<int()>` will return `true`.

`§8.3.2 [dcl.ref] p1`

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef (7.1.3) or of a template type argument (14.3), **in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored**.

and

`§4.4 [conv.qual] p3`

> [ *Note:* Function types (including those used in pointer to member function types) are never cv-qualified (8.3.5). *—end note* ]

`§8.5.3 [dcl.fct] p6`

> The effect of a *cv-qualifier-seq* in a function declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top of the function type. **In the latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored.**

Comment: In each case, what the standard says about it is that the versions of those types "with const added" are the same type again.

Comment: I added some normative text, but I can't seem to find the general wording that says repeated cv-qualifiers introduced by typedefs or template arguments are ignored. :(

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the functions are non-equal. The standard definitely does **not** require them to be identical although I suspect that it allows them to be identical (I wouldn't quite know where to look for the corresponding clause).